# wp_dequeue_style not seems to working

Tags: wordpress

I'm build a wordpress theme and I've created in my `style.css` a custom class for the plugin: [Social Count plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-count-plus/)

The problem's that plugin use an own css called `counter.css` what I need to do is prevent the inclusion of this css, so I've inserted this line in my `functions.php`:

```
wp_dequeue_style( 'counter' );
```

unfortunately the style is even included during the site reload. What am I doing wrong?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_dequeue_style('social-count-plus');
    wp_deregister_style('social-count-plus');
});
```

Comment: You can try this instead: `add_action('plugins_loaded', function() {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_dequeue_style('counter');
    wp_deregister_style('counter');
});
}`

Comment: Are you sure you have got the correct handle name..?

Comment: in the network tab I see `counter.css` that is  the file associated to the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the `counter.css` file in place but either empty it out or comment everything out. It can't load what's not there. Be aware though, and update to that plugin might add the contents of that file back.

Comment: I see. This is a theme you'll want to roll out to more than one customer.

Comment: Yes, any idea??

Comment: It's possible that after you dequeue the style, you could register a blank one.  That would be the ugly way of course. 

However, the dequeue process should work.

Comment: I just tried as the site describe with: `wp_register_style('pagination-style', plugins_url('counter.css', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_style('pagination-style');` but not working, maybe I miss something?

Comment: I don't know. But you should check the error logs and see if you can figure out why it won't dequeue your script in the first place. Maybe there is an error.

Comment: The other thing you could do is to put in a support ticket with the plugin developer and ask why it's not working.